# SD card partition table and allocted sectors very broken

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

I'm very nearly at my wits end here, fdisk gives my this. Regardless of what i do, everything ive tried it comes back like this. The card even has some music on it and I can still play it. All i want is for it to be wiped and to be usable again.
Update- I've tried the two answers and I have the same fdisk output and I can still listen to the music on it.

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 59.5 GiB, 63864569856 bytes, 124735488 sectors
Geometry: 64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 60906 cylinders
Units: cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6b736964

Device     Boot   Start     End Cylinders   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  ?     831055 1626717    795663   777G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2  ?     649505  912677    263173   257G 65 Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdb3  ?     263179  945973    682795 666.8G 53 OnTrack DM6 Aux3
/dev/sdb4  ?    1908750 1908782        32  31.9M bb Boot Wizard hidden

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

Command (m for help): v
Partition 1: overlaps partition 2.
Partition 1: overlaps partition 3.
Total allocated sectors 4866404289 greater than the maximum 124735488.
```

-

```
hartofwave@hartofwave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~$ sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sdb

***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************

Exact type match not found for type code 7400; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 6500; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code 5300; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'
Exact type match not found for type code BB00; assigning type code for
'Linux filesystem'

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
3784448450 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Warning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
The new table will be used at the next reboot.
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
```

Comment: I don't know about this...it seems like a really bad idea to try wiping a TARDIS.

Comment: Your disk might be fine, just displayed by the tool wrong / the flags aren't right. This discussion might help you: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1221693 which covers using different tools to modify the partition types, especially gparted to see what's happening in the background. Depending on the origin media, it may be intentional to have the wrong partition flags to identify the disk as the media player's own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wipe the disk, try this, either as `root` or preceded by `sudo`:

```
sgdisk -Z /dev/sdb
```

You should then be able to repartition the disk. If you can't, check the disk to see if it's got a read-only tab on it, as some (all?) SD cards do. If it's got such a tab, slide it to the other position and try again.

If that fails, then my hunch is that the disk is bad; you should chuck it in the garbage and get a new one.

Comment: This is the output 
`hartofwave@hartofwave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~$ sudo gdisk -Z /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Usage: gdisk [-l] device_file`

Comment: My apologies; it should have been `sgdisk`, not `gdisk`, in my command. I've edited my reply so it shows the correct command. Note that this command erases the partition table from the disk; it's not diagnostic.

Comment: redone it, the output is in the OP, nothing has changed again

Comment: In that case, please re-read the last paragraph of my original reply.

Answer (score 0):

This SD card is directly formatted as a single filesystem and does not actually have a partition table.  What you are seeing is ordinary filesystem data where `fdisk` is expecting the master boot record to be and it's being confused by it. That's why the partition info you are seeing is nonsensical, yet the card still works.

To wipe the card, type the following command:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=8192`

This will zero out every block on the device.

**NOTE:** The `bs=8192` is an arbitrary number.  `dd`'s default blocksize is 512 bytes, which is slow.  `BS=8192` will wipe the device in 4K chunks, which should be much faster.

**NOTE 2:** An SD card is flash-based media just like an SSD. The flash memory cells can "wear out" the more you write to them.  So don't do this too many times or you will degrade the card.

Comment: This is the output, it took a long time `hartofwave@hartofwave-Flaming-Blade-GTI:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=8192
[sudo] password for hartofwave: 
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdb’: No space left on device
7795969+0 records in
7795968+0 records out
63864569856 bytes (64 GB) copied, 2635.28 s, 24.2 MB/s
`

Comment: I think it’s extremely unlikely any filesystem could be completely parsed into a MBR partition table.

Comment: @HartOfWave, that means it worked.  It gave the error because it reached the end of the free space.  The SD card should now be blank.

Comment: @DanielB, the filesystem wouldn't fit within the partition table. Rather, the beginning of the filesystem starts at sector 0 where the partition table would normally be (if it had one). `fdisk` is seeing some filesystem data and interpreting it as a partition layout. That's why the information it's reporting is nonsense.

Comment: @WesSayeed Yeah, I didn’t express myself well enough. I’m saying that it’s unlikely that the first 512 byte of a filesystem could be interpreted as a valid partition table.

Comment: It's not just seeing something that isn’t there, there is 10gb of music still on it that can be copied and played, even after doing everything suggested and more that I’ve tried.